# Problem with returning rows using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, rows

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['flyerID']))
    $FlyerID = $_GET['flyerID'];

$DBConnect = @mysqli_connect("host", "UN", "pword")

    Or die("<p>Unable to connect to the datbase server.</p>" . "<p>Error Code ".mysqli_connect_errno().": ".mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";

$DBName = "agentsleuthdb";

@mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName)

    Or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>" . "<p>Error Code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect) . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) ."</p>";

    $TableName = "FEEDBACK";

    $SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM $TableName order by FIRSTNAME";

    $QueryResult = @mysqli_query ($DBConnect, $SQLstring)

    Or die("<p> Unable to exequte Select query.</p>"."<p>Error Code ".mysqli_errno($DBConnect) .": ".mysqli_error

($DBConnect))."</p>";

    if (mysqli_num_rows($QueryResult) == 0){

        exit("<p>There is no feedback</p>");
}

?>


            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th width = "15%">First Name </th>
                    <th width = "15%">Last Name </th>
                    <th width = "15%">Email Addr </th>
                    <th width = "15%">Company </th>
                    <th width = "40%">Feedback </th>

                </tr>


<?php
    $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);

do {
    echo "<tr><td>{$Row[0]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row[1]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row[2]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row[3]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row[4]}</td></tr>";
    $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);
} while ($Row);
mysqli_free_result($QueryResult);
mysqli_close($DBConnect);
?>
```

It only returns one row.. how can I return all entries?

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_fetch_row()` in one place and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` in another? It looks like you should be using `mysqli_fetch_row()` in the second case as well (inside of the `do` loop).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult))
```

Description [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

or

```
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($QueryResult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Description [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, only the first time you call `mysqli_fetch_row`, which makes an `$Row` an indexed array.
This is why you see output when you access the content of `$Row` with an index (`$Row[0]`, `$Row[1]`, etc..).
Afterwards, you `mysqli_fetch_assoc` which turns `$Row` in an associative array, thus accessing `$Row` with an index for your output doesn't work anymore.

Replace your `do ... while` loop by the first `while` loop aforloney suggested.